# telnet windows 7 not working

Tags: telnet, windows-7-x64

I have a Windows 7 computer, and I'm trying to work with telnet.
I installed/enabled telnet (via control panel, since telnet isn't enabled by default), restarted the terminal, restarted my computer, etc.

But telnet still doesn't work. I'm getting the error : 'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command...

I tried editing the PATH environment variable as well, but that hasn't worked either.

I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you can't manage to get telnet up and running, you can resort to [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), which has a Telnet client.

Comment: I think I might have to, thanks! None of the other suggestions worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your `telnet` is not installed. Simply execute the below command in your command prompt and wait till the [mouse progress icon](http://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursors/images3/cur257.gif) disappears. It works on windows 7. I am not sure on other machines

`pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"`

Comment: This feature was introduced from windows vista. I am not sure which windows you are using. This works for me on Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue.  Fixed it by running CMD as an admin.

Answer (score 1):

If your Windows 7 machine is a member of an AD, or if you have UAC enabled, or both, telnet must be run as an admin. The easiest way to do this is to create a shortcut that calls cdm, and then go to the shortcut's properties and click on the Advanced button and check the "Run as an administrator" checkbox, and you're all set. Scratched my head and rebooted numerous times before finding this out...